# Bootstrap 3, textarea Google Chrome issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3, textarea

I am working with Bootstrap 3 and JSP.

I'm facing with an textarea issue in Google Chrome. I mean, the value of a textarea is loaded, but when it increases the textarea seems like it doesn't mind about what is the value. Here it's an example how element fill the value.

[image]

But it does work in Firefox.
My jsp looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                    <label for="descripcionEng" class="control-label">Descripción Inglés: </label>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                    <textarea id="descripcionEng"  name="descripcionEng" class="form-control input-group">${institucionParticipante.descripcionEng}</textarea>
       </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `input-group` class from `textarea` element - it adds `position: relative` which is breaking your layout.